# OR-TOOLS ROUTING How should I construct my objective function? CVRP objective function step_function SetCumulVarSoftUpperBound routing

Tags: python, or-tools

I have a requirement to customize my objective function. My objective function is the fixed cost of the vehicle plus the cost of the number of nodes (if the number of nodes is less than or equal to 15, the cost is 0; if the number of nodes exceeds 15, the cost is (K-15)*45; if the number of nodes exceeds 20, the cost is (K-15)*38; if the number of nodes exceeds 25, the cost is (K-15)*30). How should I construct my objective function?

Currently, I am doing it like this:

```
# Fixed cost
FixedCost_list = [100,200]
# Number of free nodes
free_nums_list = [15,15]
# Vehicle ID
vehicle_id_lists = ['A','B']
# Price after exceeding the number of nodes
vehicle_nums_price_dict = {'A':{'free_nums': 15, 'more_nums_price': {(0, 5): 45, (6, 10): 38, (11, 1000):30}}, 'B': {'free_nums': 15, 'more_nums_price': {(0, 5): 45, (6, 10): 38,(11, 1000): 30}}}

for vehicle_id in range(manager.GetNumberOfVehicles()):
    index = routing.End(vehicle_id)

    # Fixed cost
    FixedCost = FixedCost_list[vehicle_id]
    routing.SetFixedCostOfVehicle(FixedCost,vehicle_id)

    # Cost per node after exceeding 15 nodes
    free_nums = free_nums_list[vehicle_id]
    more_nums_price = vehicle_nums_price_dict[vehicle_id_lists[vehicle_id]]['more_nums_price'][(0,5)]
    Nodes_dimension.SetCumulVarSoftUpperBound(index, free_nums, more_nums_price)
```

By applying soft constraints to impose penalty terms, I can constrain the number of nodes, but I cannot construct the objective function when the number of nodes exceeds 20 or 25. How can I implement the above objective function?